# Convert VB.NET code to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have three projects written with VB.NET (2005) and have to convert them to C# code. (I know that i don't need to convert codes of .net languages at all). I have no time to rewrite them, need a tool or script to convert.
Note: they are console applications.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=convert+vb.net+to+c%23

Comment: @Marek: doesn't work correctly :-)

Comment: Have you tried looking up such a tool yourself on Google?

Comment: @Gerrie Schenck: yes, but all of them was bugful.

Comment: @Gerrie: that is not a good reason not to ask the question here.

Comment: SharpDevelop IDE has a pretty decent code conversion tool.

Comment: Care to explain why you need to convert a perfectly interoperable *(well mostly)* language?

Comment: @Sorush: the point is that there are so many such tools available and findable via google that asking this on SO provides absolutely no value to you or anyone else who will find this question in the future. You did not state at all that you know of any such tools or that are giving you wrong results.

Comment: I found this via google and everyone says to use google. Yes there is info on the web, But I can't trust it, Here because of the voting and the rep I can find out what is considered by the community to be the best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) lets you inspect compiled assemblies in several different .Net languages. I've known people to cut and paste the output to convert between languages. Apparently it also has an export feature.

Comment: No need to cut an paste, you can directly save the disassembled class. ;)

Comment: reflector also has an Export option if you right click the assembly.  That will spit out the source code to the folder you specify.

Answer (score 2):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) can do this, but depending you your vb.net code a lot of manual work will remain.

Answer (score 1):

http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using [Carlos Aguilar's converter](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/). Converts from VB.NET to C# and viceversa.

Experience shows me that different converters are better than others in certain areas so I'd recommend you to use more than one, if possible, and compare their output.

Answer (score -1):

There is a cool .net code conveter tool available online here. Try this if it helps to you.
[Free Online .Net Code Converter](http://developergeeks.com/codeconverter.aspx)